# Is this a weed or an ornamental plant?

Tags: weeds

We think it showed up one year later than it was supposed to
My wife planted some bulbs and not all of them turned into a plant the year before. 
We do not know if it is a weed or one of her bulbs

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I just learned how to do a search by images or parts of an image on Pinterest. really really cool. That helped me get my answer.

[Lupine Gallery Red](http://www.americanmeadows.com/perennials/lupine/lupine-gallery-red)

The plant needs full sun. My needs to read the instructions (planted the flower in a darker corner).